# `waitForSelector` returns OK but cannot find element

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

What I want to do is that,

1. `hover` on an item of the menu so that the dropdown sub-menu will display,
2. then `hover` on an item in the dropdown sub-menu.

What I tried is as follows,

```
await page.waitForSelector(menu_item_css, {visible: true, timeout: 5000});
await page.hover(menu_item_css);

await page.waitForSelector(dropdown_menu_item_css, {visible: true, timeout: 5000});
await sleep(1000);  // line a)
await page.hover(dropdown_menu_item_css);  // line b)
```

My question is, in the above code, even if the `waitForSelector` returns successfully, without `sleep(1000)` ( see **line a)** ), **line b)** will fail instantly, with following error,

> ```
> Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
> ```

WHY?? WHY do I need to `sleep` even after `waitForSelector` returns successfully?